# why the following code does not give any results?

Tags: lua

```
printResult = ""

function print(...)
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
      printResult = printResult .. tostring(v) .. "\t"
  end
  printResult = printResult .. "\n"
  print(printResult)
end

print(...)
```

I have the above code, saved in a file with name abc.lua. After that, I have run the code/file from the command line, by `lua abc.lua`. No output shows up. Could anyone let me know how to solve this?

Comment: You have infinite recursion: function `print` invokes itself on the last line.

Comment: I think I have understood it already. I probably should call the print function in a different way, other than print(...). What do you mean about the infinite recursions?

Comment: From the `print` function, you are calling the `print` function, which in turn calls the `print` function, which in turn calls the `print` function, which in turn calls the `print` function, ......

Comment: If there is a print function readily available, declare it before your own as a local variable: `local print_old = print` and instead of calling `print(printResult)`, call `print_old(printResult)`

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. it is not what you are saying; i only call the print function once, which is the very last line of code. In side of the function definition, i did not call the print function at all.

Comment: @kkxx and what is `print(printResult)` if not a call to `print`? what is the point of calling `print(...)` if `...` is an empty list btw?

Answer (score 0):

You implemented infinite [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

The function `print` calls itself. So once you call `print` the first time your program is trapped in an infinite recursion. At some point your program will crash because your stack is full.

You do not see any output because you've overwritten Lua's standard function `print`. As Hence your function cannot create any output to the console.

```
printResult = ""

-- the following code defines a print function that calls itself 
function print(...)
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
      printResult = printResult .. tostring(v) .. "\t"
  end
  printResult = printResult .. "\n"
  -- here you call the function you're just defining
  print(printResult)
end
-- here you call print the first time which will call itself again and again...
print(...)
```

Some solutions:

a) don't call your function `print` so you can still call Lua's `print`

```
function myPrint(...)
  print("lalala")
end
```

b) create a new reference to Lua's `print` befor you create re-refer `print` to your function

```
local luaPrint = print
function print(...)
  luaPrint("lalala")
end
```

c) don't use `print` inside your function

```
function print(...)
  io.write("lalala")
end
```